# Convert an array of bytes to corresponding values based on a string input in C++

Tags: c++, unions

My program is getting an array of bytes from Serial Port and a file containing a JSON string from a web server. It has to convert the array to values based on the JSON mapping like following example:

```
uint8_t arraybyte[3]={c0,52,03}

String jsonfile="{
 "1":"name1",
 "2":"uint8_t",
 "3":"name2",
 "4":"uint16_t"
}";
```

the output must be like this

```
convertedvalues="{
     "name1":192,
     "name2":850
    }";
```

I know I need something similar to union but a union need to be declared first.

Comment: So, you have JSON data as input and JSON data as output? Use a JSON library (rapidjson, JSON for Modern C++ etc) and write converting functions between in and out.

Comment: Even without JSON lib this is not difficult to do. Why the tag _union_ ?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I want first to know if there is a library written for that before inventing wheel again

Comment: @bruno I had a module that I customized it when something would change. I Used to use union to deserialize my input but i want know to generalize it and when protocol changes I change input not modifying code

Comment: If that's what you'd like, search for `JSON transform` and you may find something useful. I haven't used any JSON transformation libraries myself though.